# Create formula to add classes based on field length

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, advanced-custom-fields

I need some insight on how to create a formula that will determine what class to add to a `div` element based on the number of div's being displayed.

Currently I am using ACF to create a repeater field that will have one sub-field that links to a page based what the admin selects. These fields will display in their own div's based on a while loop. I am using Bootstrap classes such as `col-sm-12`, `col-sm-6`, and `col-sm-4`.

```
while( have_rows( 'project_repeater' ) ): the_row();

    $post_object = get_sub_field( 'project_type' );

    $count = count( get_field('project_repeater') ); // Output 4

    $mod = $count % 3; // Output 1

    if( $post_object ):

        $post = $post_object;
        setup_postdata( $post );

        $classname = '';

        if( $mod == 1 ) {

            if( $count == 1 ) {
                $classname .= 'col-sm-12';
            } elseif( $count == 4 ) {
                $classname .= 'col-sm-6';
            } else { // $count == 7
                $classname .= 'col-sm-4';
            }

        } elseif( $mod == 2 ) {

            if( $count == 2 ) {
                $classname .= 'col-sm-6';
            } elseif( $count == 5 ) {
                // $classname .= 'col-sm-12';
            } else { // $count == 8
                // $classname .= 'col-sm-4';
            }

        } else { // $mod == 0
            $classname .= 'col-sm-4';
        }

        ?>
        <div class="project-cat <?php echo $classname; ?>">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink( $post ); ?>">
                <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php

        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;

endwhile;
```

Now when `$count == 5`, I need it to set the first 3 div's to have `col-sm-4` and then the last 2 div's to have `col-sm-6` (this will display the divs in this order stacked on top of each other: 3,2).

When `$count == 7`, it will need to be similar to when `$count == 5` but have the first 3 as `col-sm-4` and the last 4 as `col-sm-6` (3,2,2)

When `$count == 8`, it will be slightly different where I have the first 6 as `col-sm-4` and the last 2 as `col-sm-6` (3,3,2).

Instead of using `if` statement after if statement, there has to be a better way to create a formula that will determine which class to use based on the number of `div` elements that are being displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to you Nick you helped me out a lot, I did find what I was doing wrong and why it wasn't displaying like you said it would. I was not defining `$i` properly. But here is the code and everything works! Thanks again to you Nick!

```
$count = count( get_field('project_repeater') );

$limit = floor( $count / 3 ) * 3;

$remaining = $count - $limit;

$i = 0;

while( have_rows( 'project_repeater' ) ): the_row();

    $post_object = get_sub_field( 'project_type' );

    if( $i < $limit ) {
        $classname = 'col-sm-4';
    } else {
        if( $remaining == 1 ) {
            $classname = 'col-sm-12';
        }
        if( $remaining == 2 ) {
            $classname = 'col-sm-6';
        }
    }

    if( $post_object ):

        $post = $post_object;
        setup_postdata( $post );

        ?>
        <div class="project-cat <?php echo $classname; ?>">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink( $post ); ?>">
                <h5><?php the_title(); ?></h5>
                <p><?php the_excerpt(); ?></p>
            </a>
        </div>
        <?php

        wp_reset_postdata();
    endif;

    $i++;

endwhile;
```

Comment: Kudos! :) Great job :) Good to hear I was helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

This is more math and logic problem rather than coding problem.

Why don't you 1. get the number of elements.

divide by 3 and floor the result. So you can know how many rows of col-xx-4 you are going to have.

let's say you have 14 items in total. Than fist 12 element should have col-md-4.
if you  round 14/3 = 4
what is left is 14 - (3*4) = 2 so if what is left is 1 than you can use col-md-12 class, if it is 2 than col-md-6.

so while outputting you assign class col-md-4 to first 12 elements (round 14/3 = 4) and then assign appropriate class to the remaining elements (14 - (3*4) = 2) based on their number (1 or 2)

Do you think it will work for you?

## Sequence

set a few variables

$total = total number of items. You can simply run the loop with a counter.

```
$md4-limit = floor($total/3)*3;
$remaining = $total - $md4-limit;
```

then when you are running the loop, use the $i and for each element increment that value and when outputting check

```
if ($i <= $md4-limit) {
$class = ' col-md-4 ';
} else {
 if($remaining == 1) { $class = ' col-md-12 '; }
 if($remaining == 2) { $class = ' col-md-6 '; }

}
```

then echo class into column html where the class should be :)

ANOTHER option is to add row width options to the your ACF repeater field and just construct the grid on the back end.

Comment: This was extremely helpful Nick! Thank you, I am struggling how to echo out the last div (if the remainder is 1) to have a different class than the first 12 divs, from your example.

Comment: You're welcome. I will modify my answer now to address your question.

Comment: So now that I see your example, I'm slightly confused to why I would use $i and `foreach` element

Comment: $i if for counting the number of current element that is being output and instead of foreach you will just use while( have_rows( 'project_repeater' ) ): the_row();

Comment: Thanks for the clarification nick! This seems to work but, the issue that i'm running into is instead of applying the extra classes of `col-sm-12` or `col-sm-6` if there is 1 or two left is not working. It seems to applying `col-sm-4` not matter what. If I only have two rows displaying, it should direct the class to `col-sm-6`.. the same as if I had 4 rows, it should be the first 3 as `col-sm-4` and the last one as `col-sm-12` but its only applying the `col-sm-4`

Comment: You are doing something wrong probably. I have designed several grid layouts for danish design award website when I was building it with such logic but I also needed to develop custom javascript library for keeping everything in place. In your case it is easier just try to test every step and check if all the variables and counters are set correctly.